# JavaFX TitledPane changed title background is reset on mouse entered

Tags: java, css, javafx

I need to change the TitledPane title background based on some incoming value during runtime and reset it otherwise.

All my TitledPane's is styled on a CSS attached to the Scene.

Changing the background is no problem.
The problem is when the mouse enters over the title after the background has been changed, the background is thus reset to the background from CSS.

Test application for changing TitledPane title background:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TitledPaneApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final StackPane root = new StackPane();

        final TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
        titledPane.setText("Title");
        root.getChildren().add(titledPane);

        final String titleBackgroundValue = "#00ff11";
        final ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton("Change");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            boolean selected = button.isSelected();

            final Node node = titledPane.lookup(".title");
            if (selected) {
                final Color color = Color.valueOf(titleBackgroundValue);
                ((Region) node).setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(color, null, null)));
            } else {
                ((Region) node).setBackground(null);
                titledPane.applyCss();
            }
        });

        button.setSelected(false);
        titledPane.setContent(button);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("light.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TestApplication");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

The Scene CSS light.css

```
.root {
    -fx-base: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    -fx-background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    -fx-border-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);

    /* make controls (buttons, thumb, etc.) slightly lighter */
    -fx-color: derive(-fx-base, 10%);

    /* text fields and table rows background */
    -fx-control-inner-background: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    /* version of -fx-control-inner-background for alternative rows */
    -fx-control-inner-background-alt: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -2.5%);

    /* text colors depending on background's brightness */
    -fx-light-text-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    -fx-mid-text-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    -fx-dark-text-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);

    /* A bright blue for highlighting/accenting objects.  For example: selected
     * text; selected items in menus, lists, trees, and tables; progress bars */
    -fx-accent: rgb(0, 80, 100);

    /* color of non-focused yet selected elements */
    -fx-selection-bar-non-focused: rgb(50, 50, 50);

    -fx-font-family: "Roboto"; /* "Segoe UI Semibold", "Roboto", "Monospaced" */
    -fx-font-size: 1em;

    -primary-border-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

/* Fix derived prompt color for text fields */
.text-input {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -50%);
}

/* Keep prompt invisible when focused (above color fix overrides it) */
.text-input:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;
}

/* Fix scroll bar buttons arrows colors */
.scroll-bar > .increment-button > .increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

.scroll-bar > .increment-button:hover > .increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button:hover > .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

.scroll-bar > .increment-button:pressed > .increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button:pressed > .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.text-field {
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
}

.combo-box {
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
}

/* ScrollPane style. */
.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.scroll-pane > .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

/* TabPane style. */
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

/* TitledPane style. */
.titled-pane {
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-border-color: -primary-border-color;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 5, 0.0, 0, 1);
}

.titled-pane > .content {
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}

.titled-pane .title .arrow-button {
    visibility: false;
}

.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-color: -primary-border-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
}

.titled-pane > .title .text {
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Comment: Where is `-primary-border-color` defined?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added it to the CSS example.

Comment: Very weird. I have tried many methods of correcting this and I can't isolate the property that is being triggered when hovering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting inline CSS styling takes the priority over from the styles in css file. So applying the background through setStyle will do the trick.

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {
            final Node node = titledPane.lookup(".title");
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                node.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#00ff11;");
            } else {
                node.setStyle(null);
            }
        });
```

***UPDATE:***
However, a bit more details on the actual problem. To understand this, you need to first know how the background of .title is defined internally and how the hover styling is set.

Internally in Modena.css below are the styling for the background of .title:

```
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(to bottom,
            derive(-fx-color,-15%) 95%,
            derive(-fx-color,-25%) 100%
        ),
        -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3 3 0 0, 2 2 0 0, 1 1 0 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.3333em 0.75em 0.3333em 0.75em; /* 4 9 4 9 */
}

.titled-pane > .title:hover {
    -fx-color: -fx-hover-base;
}
```

If you notice the actual background is derived from -fx-color, -fx-inner-border & -fx-body-color. However -fx-inner-border & -fx-body-color are indeed again derived from -fx-color only.

```
-fx-inner-border: linear-gradient(to bottom,
                ladder(
                    -fx-color,
                    derive(-fx-color,30%) 0%,
                    derive(-fx-color,20%) 40%,
                    derive(-fx-color,25%) 60%,
                    derive(-fx-color,55%) 80%,
                    derive(-fx-color,55%) 90%,
                    derive(-fx-color,75%) 100%
                ),
                ladder(
                    -fx-color,
                    derive(-fx-color,20%) 0%,
                    derive(-fx-color,10%) 20%,
                    derive(-fx-color,5%) 40%,
                    derive(-fx-color,-2%) 60%,
                    derive(-fx-color,-5%) 100%
                ));
                
-fx-body-color: linear-gradient(to bottom,
            ladder(
                -fx-color,
                derive(-fx-color,8%) 75%,
                derive(-fx-color,10%) 80%
            ),
            derive(-fx-color,-8%));
```

In the :hover pseudo state, the -fx-color is changed to -fx-hover-base and the background is updated accordingly. **There lies your problem**. You are setting only the default background programatically. On mouse over the .title, it **still picks** the internally CSS file styling (as you have not defined your custom one for hover).

If we manage to update the -fx-color attribute, then it will take care of the corresponding css updates for different pseudo states.

A more correct approach for your requirement will be as below: this way you can still get the nice gradient features of title which are internally defined.

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {
            final Node node = titledPane.lookup(".title");
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                node.setStyle("-fx-color:#00ff11;");
            } else {
                node.setStyle(null);
            }
        });
    
// In css file  
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-color: -primary-border-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Please find below an example for TitledPane inside another TitledPane.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Set;

public class TitledPaneApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);

        final TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
        titledPane.setText("Title");

        final String titleBackgroundValue = "#00ff11";
        final ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton("Change");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            final Set<Node> node = titledPane.lookupAll(".title");
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                node.forEach(n->n.setStyle("-fx-color:#00ff11;"));
            } else {
                node.forEach(n->n.setStyle(null));
            }
        });
        button.setSelected(false);

        VBox inner = new VBox();
        inner.setSpacing(10);
        inner.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        final TitledPane innerTP = new TitledPane();
        innerTP.setText("Inner Title");
        inner.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Inner"),innerTP);
        innerTP.setContent(new Button("Dummy Button"));

        titledPane.setContent(inner);

        root.getChildren().addAll(button,titledPane);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("light.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TestApplication");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. It will not reset on hovering. Though I would like to find out why my programmatically approach didn't work.

Comment: @DJViking Updated my answer for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I realize this is a very old answer, but I am hoping someone could explain how to do this when the `TitledPane` contains another `TitledPane`. Only the child pane is selected when looking up ".title" and not the parent.

Comment: @Zephyr, have you tried using lookupAll method. I updated the answer with the example. Let me know if you have a different scenario.

Comment: @SaiDandem - I did solve it using the `lookupAll` method shortly after writing my comment. The only drawback there is that it then updates **all** of the `TitledPane` objects under the parent. Would prefer to affect just the single parent. I will look into the docs and see if there's an order to the `Set<>` being returned.

Comment: @Zephyr, one way i can think of is to traverse through heirarchy and collect the required nodes. I updated the previous example to have multi level titled panes and change styling for the deepest 2 titled panes. Check if that suites your purpose...